# Ayuda con consultas sql Oracle Esquema hr

Tags: oracle, sql

Necesito ayuda con estos ejercicios.

Adjunto el modelo entidad relación de la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Muestra todos los empleados que fueron contratados el día de la semana en el que se contrató el mayor número de empleados.
   Tengo que recuperar los empleados del día que tiene mayor número de contrataciones.
   De momento, tengo una consulta que me devuelve los días, y el número de empleados que se ha contratado ese día.

   ```
   select to_char(e1.hire_date,'day') as "D",count(*) as "C"
   from employees e1
   where to_char(e1.hire_date,'day') = (select to_char(hire_date,'day') from employees where employee_id=e1.employee_id)
   group by to_char(e1.hire_date,'day')
   ```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces según ese resultado, tengo que recuperar los empleados contratados en un día sábado o viernes, ya que ese día tiene el mayor número de contrataciones.

2. Muestre el número de departamento, el nombre del departamento y el número de empleados que trabajan en él y que tiene el mayor número de empleados:
   Para este tengo que recuperar el departamento que tiene mayor número de empleados.
   Tengo el siguiente *query* que me muestra el número de empleados máximo, me falta agregar, el nombre del departamento y código, pero cuando agrego esos campos, la consulta me devuelve que la función de grupo no es un grupo único.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quito el campo del *department_id*, me devuelve el número de empleados máximos que tiene un departamento.

```
select d.department_id as "ID",max(count(*)) as "Num Empleados"
from departments d, employees e
where d.department_id=e.department_id
group by d.department_id
;
```

Comment: El ejercicio 1 dice "día de la semana", (domingo, lunes, etc), y tu lo estás haciendo por día del mes.

Comment: @jachguate es verdad, no lo había notado, corregiré la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambas consultas requieren un razonamiento similar. Encontrar registros asociados a *algo* que tiene el mayor número de *empleados*.

Por esta razón, te ayudaré a resolver el primer ejercicio y dejaré que resuelvas por tu cuenta el segundo, lo cual ayudará a que te esfuerces en comprender la solución del primero.

Para ello, vamos a ir por pasos.

1. Necesitamos primero determinar cuantas contrataciones se hicieron por día de la semana. Esta consulta ya *casi* la tienes. Yo la escribiría de la siguiente manera:

   ```
    select   to_char(emp.hire_date, 'D')  DiaSemana
           , count(1) Contrataciones
      from hr.employees emp
     group by to_char(emp.hire_date, 'D')
   ```

   Lo que cambia es que obtengo el día de la semana con un número (que va de 1 a 7, lo cual hace más eficiente la comparación. El efecto no se percibe con un conjunto pequeño de datos y no suelo optimizar prematuramente, pero en este caso, es tan natural y sin esfuerzo que siempre prefiero la forma que me parece más óptima. Lo otro es que doy nombres descriptivos a las columnas. Esto hace que el resto del SQL sea más legible.
2. Ahora, necesitamos alguna manera de determinar cual de estos es el que tiene el contador más alto, ya que ese es el registro que nos interesa. Se me ocurre que podemos agregar una columna que nos dirá el número de fila de cada registro al ordenar el resultado por el contador de registros de manera descendente. Para lograrlo, me valgo de la función de ventana `row_number()`. La consulta entonces quedaría así:

   ```
    select   to_char(emp.hire_date, 'D')  DiaSemana
           , count(1) Contrataciones
           , row_number() over (order by count(1) desc, to_char(emp.hire_date, 'D')) NoFila
      from hr.employees emp
     group by to_char(emp.hire_date, 'D')
   ```

   Si hay dos o más días de la semana que coinciden con el mismo contador, quedarán ordenados por el número del día de la semana de manera ascendente. Hago esto para que el motor me de siempre el mismo resultado, solo en caso de haber *colisión* en el contador más alto.
3. Colocaré la consulta anterior en un *CTE*, llamado `ContratosPorDiaSemana` y ya puedo hacer `join` de mi tabla de empleados con este resultado, para finalmente filtrar solo los que tengan `NoFila` igual a 1, que es el día con más registros de contrataciones. A la lista completa de campos de la tabla de empleados, le estoy agregando el número de día de la semana, en el resultado final. Todas las piezas juntas quedan así:

   ```
    with 
    ContratosPorDiaSemana as ( 
    select   to_char(emp.hire_date, 'D')  DiaSemana 
           , count(1) Contrataciones 
           , row_number() over (order by count(1) desc, to_char(emp.hire_date, 'D')) NoFila 
      from hr.employees emp 
     group by to_char(emp.hire_date, 'D') 
    ) 
    select emp.*, cdia.DiaSemana 
      from hr.employees emp 
           inner join ContratosPorDiaSemana cdia on cdia.DiaSemana = to_char(emp.hire_date, 'D')  
     where cdia.NoFila = 1
   ```

He dejado [la consulta en oracle live](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/kn5qb918vjueeqmgcoqtnwzcr), que tiene montada esa base de datos de ejemplo, por lo que se puede probar directamente con ese mismo esquema.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a la ayuda de **jachguate** logré resolver los ejercicios de la siguiente manera, no se si sea la más óptima pero tenía que resolverlo solo con las herramientas que me habían enseñado.

Para el ejercicio 1.

```
select employee_id as "Codigo", first_name as "Nombre", hire_date from (select aux.D from (select to_char(e1.hire_date,'d') as "D",count(*) as "C"
from employees e1
where to_char(e1.hire_date,'d') = (select to_char(hire_date,'d') from employees where employee_id=e1.employee_id)
group by to_char(e1.hire_date,'d')
order by 2 desc) aux
where rownum=1) , employees
where to_char(hire_date,'d')=D
;
```

Básicamente lo que hice fue primero, agrupar el número de empleados contratados por día de la semana, estos los ordené de manera descendente para luego obtener solo la primera fila de esa consulta, de esa manera obtengo el día en que se contrataron más empleados; esta idea la tomé de la respuesta anterior. Luego ya solo basta comparar los empleados contratados de acuerdo a esa fila.

Para el ejercicio 2.

```
select department_id as "Departamento", department_name as "Nombre", NE as "Total Empleados" from (select dep.ID, dep.NE from (select d.department_id as "ID",count(*) as "NE"
from departments d, employees e
where d.department_id=e.department_id
group by d.department_id,e.department_id
order by 2 desc) dep 
where rownum=1) aux, departments
where department_id=ID
;
```

Al igual que el primero, agrupe los departamentos de acuerdo al número de empleados que tiene cada departamento, los ordené descendente-mente y recuperé la primera fila de esa consulta, para luego recuperar el nombre, codigo del departamento de acuerdo a los valores de esa primera consulta.